# Get a submitted form value using jQuery, have more than 1 form with the same class name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've tried to search for an answer here but there are no answers that match what I need. I have more than 1 form with class name `.sbt-form`:

```html
<form class='sbt-form'>
    <input name='kord' val=1/>
</form>

<form class='sbt-form'>
    <input name='kord' val=2/>
</form>

<form class='sbt-form'>
    <input name='kord' val=3/>
</form>
```

When one form is submitted (let's say the third one) I want just to get the value of `input` element with `name = 'kord'`

How do i do this using jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach a `submit` handler to the forms and search within them for the element you want to find. Try this:

```
$('.sbt-form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the form submission to the server. Comment this if not needed.
    var inputValue = $(this).find('input[name=kord]').val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('.sbt-form').click(function() {
    $(this).find("input[name='kord']").val(); 
});
```

Comment: Please expand by editing your answer. Why would that solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$("mySubmitButton").click(function () {
    $(this).closest(".sbt-form").find("input[name='kord']").val();
});
```

Comment: Please expand by editing your answer. Why would that solve the problem?

Comment: Well, it do exactly what you asked for. It get the value of the input when the submit button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

OR you can get whole form's value with `serialize()` function on submitting the form:

JS Code:

```
$(".sbt-form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).serialize());
});
```